# ExceptionInInitializerError thrown when creating new stage

Tags: java, swing, exception

I'm using swing `JFrame` as MainFrame for my application. I have a button which should create a new window. But it will crash right in initialization and I have no clue why.

```
public class Dialog {
    private Stage window;

 public void display() {
    window = new Stage(); //This is line 45. This is place where it crash
    window.setMinWidth(350);
    window.setMinHeight(500);
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle("Add new Stuff");
 //more code here
 }
}
```

Here is whole exception error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1179)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:236)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:224)
    at main.Dialog.display(Dialog.java:45)
    at main.MainFrame.jButtonAddZamActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:400)
    at main.MainFrame.access$400(MainFrame.java:12)
    at main.MainFrame$5.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:227)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:245)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:674)
    at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:80)
    ... 43 more
```

Any ideas why is it crashing? Thanks

Comment: *"This operation is permitted on the event thread only"* ... tried to google for that?

Comment: I know only one way how to create a dialog window. Via stage. I never used other method and I have no idea how to do that. Also I don't know what does mean "event thread".

Comment: Why try to mix Swing with Java-FX? Except with good reason, make it one or the other..

Comment: Why are you using a JavaFX stage inside a `JFrame`/Swing app? *"This operation is permitted on the event thread only"* should have been a good starting point for your research

Comment: If you're really up for the challenge of mix JavaFX and Swing, you better start by having a look at [JavaFX: Interoperability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)

Comment: Well, like I said I used always only Stage for dialogs so I never thought that it's FX only. In that case it makes sense. I should remake my JFrame into FX app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have JavaFx component inside a swing application. We did that for one the ERP application to display dashboard with JavaFx Charts.

[image]

Initializing JavaFx related code should be done as below.

```
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
       });
```

Please refer below link for more details
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: The link you've provided is awesome!  I tried to make it in FX, but I had terrible problems with TableView, but this solved my problem quite quickly. Thanks!